# EmailAgent for Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am new to salesforce and following trailhead. I was trying to open a link but it does not exist anymore. The link is: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/website/emailagent.zip

Github link:
https://github.com/vitkin/sfdc-email-to-case-agent

Does anyone know from where can I download this file? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a problem with trailhead's content (which one?) your best option would be to contact the admins directly and/or check the forum (links are on right hand side, for example in https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/alm_deployment/units/alm_sandbox).

Do you really need this Agent? If I remember correctly it's something you need to install on the machine where your company's mail server is... It's somewhat ancient solution, SF now offers Email-to-Case service where your own Apex code can handle inbound emails.

I really think this solution is dead. if you go in your Setup -> Email-to-Case and try "Download the Email-to-Case agent from the Apex Developer Network" link it leads to content accessible only by SF employees.